# Is it faster to use local `foo = require "foo"` rather than `foo = require "foo"`

Tags: lua, global, local, love2d

Will my program have faster access to the functions/variables stored in foo, if foo is local?
And if i use `local foo = require "foo"` in multiple files will foo.lua be loaded multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Access to local values do one less hash lookup and will be faster. If it will be noticeable or not depends on how you use it - i.e. if amount of access to this table is relatively high to anything else your program does.

`require` will only load any given module once. As [docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) say:

> The function starts by looking into the package.loaded table to
>   determine whether modname is already loaded. If it is, then require
>   returns the value stored at package.loaded[modname].